# How do I include a select from a different table in a DB2 select case

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a fairly large query running on a DB2 server.  In that query I have a case statement with 20 options.  This case works perfectly until I try to put a subquery in each when clause. Then it gives me an error and we are not sure where it occurs.

```
Select SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCLNT,
  (Select SCDATA.SCCLNT.CNAME From SCDATA.SCCLNT
  Where SCDATA.SCCLNT.CLTGRP Like '231043' Fetch First
    1 Rows Only) As ClientName,
  CONCAT(TRIM(SCDATA.SCCLNT.CADD1), SCDATA.SCCLNT.CADD2) As Address1,
  CONCAT(TRIM(SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCITY), CONCAT(', ',
  CONCAT(TRIM(SCDATA.SCCLNT.CSTATE), CONCAT('  ',             
TRIM(SCDATA.SCCLNT.CZIP)))))
  As Address2,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CLTGRP As Group,
  CONCAT((Select     
VARCHAR_FORMAT(Min(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Cast(SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT
    As Char(10)), 'YYYYMMDD')), 'MM/DD/YYYY') From SCDATA.SCACCT
  Where SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT Between 20170401 and 20170501), CONCAT(' -     ',
  (Select VARCHAR_FORMAT(Max(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(Cast(SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT     As
    Char(10)), 'YYYYMMDD')), 'MM/DD/YYYY') From SCDATA.SCACCT
  Where SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT Between 20170401 and 20170501))) As     dateRange,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GCLNT,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLACE,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GACCT# As GACCTnum,
  CONCAT(TRIM(SCDATA.SCACCT.GLAST), CONCAT(', ',     TRIM(SCDATA.SCACCT.GFIRST))) As
  Debtor,
  ( SCDATA.SCACCT.GPRI +  SCDATA.SCACCT.GINT) as Balance,
   SCDATA.SCACCT.Gdebt#,
CASE
   WHEN GDC20 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC20     FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC19 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC19 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC18 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC18 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC17 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC17     FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC16 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC16 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC15 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC15 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC14 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC14 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC13 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC13 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC12 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC12 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC11 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC11 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC10 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC10 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC09 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC09 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS)
   WHEN GDC08 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC08 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC07 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC07 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC06 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC06 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC05 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC05 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC04 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC04 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC03 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC03 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC02 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC02 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   WHEN GDC01 !='' THEN  (Select SDDESC from SC0016 where SDCODE=GDC01 FETCH TOP 1 ROWS) 
   ELSE 'xx'
END as Description


From SCDATA.SCCLNT
  inner Join SCDATA.SCACCT On SCDATA.SCACCT.GCLNT = SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCLNT     And
    SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT Between 20170401 and 20170501
Where SCDATA.SCCLNT.CLTGRP Like '231043'
Group By SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCLNT,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CLTGRP,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CNAME,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CADD1,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CADD2,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCITY,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CSTATE,
  SCDATA.SCCLNT.CZIP,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GFIRST,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GLAST,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GCLNT,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLACE,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GPLDAT,
  SCDATA.SCACCT.GACCT#,
SCDATA.SCACCT.gpri,
SCDATA.SCACCT.GINT,
SCDATA.SCACCT.GDEBT#,
GDC20,
GDC19,
GDC18,
GDC17,
GDC16,
GDC15,
GDC14,
GDC13,
GDC12,
GDC11,
GDC10,
GDC09,
GDC08,
GDC07,
GDC06,
GDC05,
GDC04,
GDC03,
GDC02,
GDC01
```

The purpose behind this query is to get the highest ranking description code for display in the query results, but the program is built so that descriptions are added over time so I need to count down from 20 to 1 to find the most recently used code.  The codes are a simple 2 character combination which corresponds to another table where I need to pull the information.

The question is how can I redesign the case statement in DB2 to pull the single value I need out of the SC0016 table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, it turns out, was to put the select case in the join statement.  So in the select portion I would list the field I wanted, SDDESC, and in the join I would 
    LEFT JOIN SC0016 on SDCODE = 
    CASE When GDC20!='' then GDC20 ... end

This will allow me to join each row based on the highest populated column in the first table.  Not very normalized but I didn't write the database :)  This works.